# Solving "CUDA out of memory" when fine-tuning GPT-2 (HuggingFace)

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I get the reoccuring CUDA out of memory error when using the HuggingFace Transformers library to fine-tune a GPT-2 model and can't seem to solve it, despite my 6 GB GPU capacity, which I thought should be enough for fine-tuning on texts. The error reads as follows:

```
File "GPT\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "GPT\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_utils.py", line 1763, in forward
    x = torch.addmm(self.bias, x.view(-1, x.size(-1)), self.weight)
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 144.00 MiB (GPU 0; 6.00 GiB total capacity; 4.28 GiB already allocated; 24.50 MiB free; 4.33 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF
```

I already set batch size to as low as 2 and reduced training examples without success. I also tried to migrate the code to Colab, where the 12GB RAM were quickly consumed.
My examples are rather long, some counting 2.400 characters, but they should be truncated by the model automatically. My (German) examples look like this:

```
 Er geht in fremde Wohnungen, balgt sich mit Freund und Feind, ist
zudringlich zu unsern Sämereien und Kirschen.  Wenn die Gesellschaft nicht groß
ist, lasse ich sie gelten und streue ihnen sogar Getreide.  Sollten sie hier
aber doch zu viel werden, so hilft die Windbüchse, und sie werden in den
Meierhof hinabgescheucht.  Als einen bösen Feind zeigte sich der Rotschwanz.  Er
flog zu dem Bienenhause und schnappte die Tierchen weg.  Da half nichts, als ihn
ohne Gnade mit der Windbüchse zu töten.

 Ich wollte
Ihnen mein Wort halten, liebe Mama, aber die Versuchung war zu groß.  Da bin ich
eines Abends in den Keller gegangen und hab' aus allen Fässern den Spund
herausgeklopft.  Bis auf den letzten Tropfen ist das Gift ausgeronnen aus den
Fässern.  Der Schade war groß, aber der Teufel war aus dem Haus. «

Andor lachte.  »Mama, das Geschrei hätten Sie hören sollen! Als ob der
Weltuntergang gekommen wäre. Er bedauerte beinahe seine
Schroffheit.  Nun, nachlaufen wird er ihnen nicht, die werden schon selber
kommen.  Aber bewachen wird er seine Kolonie bei Tag und bei Nacht lassen
müssen.  Hol' der Teufel diesen Mercy.  Muß der gerade in Högyész ein Kastell
haben.  Wenn einer von den Schwarzwäldern dahin kommt und ihn verklagt.
```

Is there a problem with the data formatting maybe?
If anyone has a hint on how to solve this, it would be very welcome.

EDIT: Thank you [Timbus Calin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6117017/timbus-calin) for the answer, I described in the comment how adding the **`block_size`** flag to the config.json solved the problem. Here is the whole configuration for reference:

```
{
    "model_name_or_path": "dbmdz/german-gpt2",
    "train_file": "Fine-Tuning Dataset/train.txt",
    "validation_file": "Fine-Tuning Dataset/test.txt",
    "output_dir": "Models",
    "overwrite_output_dir": true,
    "per_device_eval_batch_size": 8,
    "per_device_train_batch_size": 8,
    "block_size": 100, 
    "task_type": "text-generation",
    "do_train": true,
    "do_eval": true
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If the memory problems still persist, you could opt for
   `DistillGPT2`, as it has a 33% reduction in the parameters of the
   network (the forward pass is also twice as fast). Particularly for a small GPU memory like 6GB VRAM, it could
   be a solution/alternative to your problem.
2. At the same time, it depends on how you preprocess the data. Indeed,
   the model is capable of "receiving" a maximum length of `N` tokens
   (could be for example `512/768`) depending on the models you choose. I
   recently trained a named entity recognition model and the model
   had a maximum length of `768` tokens. However, when I manually set the
   dimension of the padded tokens in my PyTorch `DataLoader()` to a big
   number, I also got OOM memory (**even** on `3090 24GB VRAM`). As I reduced
   the dimension of the tokens to a much smaller one (`512` instead of
   `768` for example) the training started to work and I did not get
   any issues with the lack of memory.

TLDR: Reducing the number of tokens in the preprocessing phase, regardless of the max capacity of the network, can also help to solve your memories problem.

**Note that** reducing the number of tokens to process in a sequence is different from the dimension of a token.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. Your second suggestion to check the input token size solved the problem. When fine-tuning the GPT-2 language model there is a flag `block_size` in the config.json, which I now set to 100 (with 1024 being the default). This chunks the input into batches of 100 tokens each, which then can be processed even with 6GB VRAM. I am adding the complete configuration to my original answer as a help for anyone with similar problems.

Comment: I am actually very happy to have solved your problem, it gives me joy.